# Return object as json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this class.

```
public class SDS
{
    public Guid A { get; set; }

    public Guid B { get; set; }

    public String C { get; set; }
}
```

I return the json like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Val()
        {

                SDS svr = new SDS();
                svr.A = ...
                svr.B = ...
                svr.C = ...

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json_serializer.Serialize(svr), "application/json");
}
```

In the client side I use jquery like this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
```

The problem is that the json that gets returned is like this and I am unable to iterate ofer the values or access the elements via index:

```
{"A":"3a9779fe-9c92-4208-b34d-5113e0548d50","B":"206575a5-8a90-4a13-89ec-910e5a9a35a1","C":"Meta"}
```

To solve this issue I had to do this and this works:

```
obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"List":[' + obj + ']}');
```

**My question is is there any way to use an attribute on the class so that it returns a json that I can use?**

```
[SomeAttribute name="List"]
public class SDS
{
    public Guid A { get; set; }

    public Guid B { get; set; }

    public String C { get; set; }
}
```

...
...
...

**Update2:**

**This question is still open as none of the provided answers were able to produce a fix.**

Answer (score 2):

You can return a [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) by calling [`Json()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in your action method.

```
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var item = ...
    return Json(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context. Probably because I use WEB API

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the JsonResult from [System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) ?

```
public JsonResult Val()  {}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I forgot to note that I am using WEB API

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're returning a single object, not a list, but you could do:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Val()
{

    SDS svr = new SDS();
    svr.A = ...
    svr.B = ...
    svr.C = ...

    var list = new {List = new [] {svr}};

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json_serializer.Serialize(svr), "application/json");
}
```

Comment: var list = new {List = svr};  returns {"List":{"A":"3a9779fe-9c92-4208-b34d-5113e0548d50","B":"206575a5-8a90-4a13-89ec-910e5a9a35a1","C":"Meta"}} and not  {"List":[{"A":"3a9779fe-9c92-4208-b34d-5113e0548d50","B":"206575a5-8a90-4a13-89ec-910e5a9a35a1","C":"Meta"}]} as it should for it to work

Comment: I have no idea why, but your code returns the json like this "{"List":[{...}]}", instead of like this {"List":[{...}]}. jQuery.parseJSON fails to parse the "{"List":[{...}]}"

Comment: Looks like things have changed for WebAPI.  I'll edit my answer to go back to your original method.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON returned is correct, don't change anything in your controller

..but in your JS loop the object with a for in loop

```
for(var propertyName in obj){
     ...
}
```

propertyName gives you A, B and C
and...

```
var value = obj[propertyName]
```

gives you the value

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON fails to parse the json into an array, so obj[n] does not work.

Comment: For in works on an object, it accesses the properties of the object like you were going through the keys of a dictionary, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: Use this to get the obj:  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

Comment: Sure, I am doing exactly that and it fails to parse the json into an array.

Answer (score 0):

add ApiController and using System.Web.Http;

Comment: This is too short to be a good answer. Please consider expanding it or moving it to a comment.